# image_to_string not returning anything Python

Tags: python, string, image, loops, screenshot

As it's in title, I have get into problem of getting text of an screenshot that's updating every less than second. But unfortunately am not getting any return value from image_to_string. What am doing wrong? My codes are bellow:

```
def WindowScreenshot(window_title=None):
    if window_title:
        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
        if hwnd:
            x, y, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
            x, y = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (x,y))
            x1, y1 = win32gui.ClientToScreen(hwnd, (x1 - x, y1 - y))
            im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x + 50, y + 147, x1 - 665, y1 - 528))
            im.save("images/1.png")
        else:
            print("Window not fount!")
    else:
        im = pyautogui.screenshot()
        im.save("images/1.png")
```

Screenshot is saving properly (updating quick)

```
while True:
    # So here on loop am getting screenshot from a window title
    im = WindowScreenshot("Windowed Projector (Preview)")
    img = Image.open("images/1.png")
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    print(text)
```

Comment: first check what you have in image `.png` - maybe you don't have text on image. Second: pytesseract works better if you have black text on white background with 300dpi. Too small text can makes problem. See aso doc: [Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Comment: what text do you want to get? Maybe there are better methods to get it - ie. using `win32gui`